# How to call vue methods inside jquery event?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, webpack

I’m using vue with webpack.
This is my code:

```
export default {
data() {
        return {
            start: true,
            logReg: false,
        }
},
methods: {
    checkLogged() {
        this.start = false;
        this.logReg = true;

    },
    closem(pathTo) {
        $('#mm').modal('hide')
        this.$router.push({ path: pathTo })

    }
},
mounted() {


    $('#mm').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {


       this.checkLogged();




    });
},
}
```

I’m trying to call “checkLogged” method inside the jquery event but it says the function is undefined.
How can i call the method?

Comment: Just a note here. You should not mix Jquery with any framework. I'm sure there is a way to acheive what you are trying to do directly in vue.

Comment: Explain please..

Comment: Well jquery is a very intrusive "framework" and most of the time it will interfere with the framework you are trying to use. It's better to only use the function that are supported by that framework to do what you are trying to do. This goes for any JS frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `function() {...}` creates a new scope, therefore the `this` inside the callback does not actually refer to the VueJS component anymore, but to the window object instead.

You can use an arrow function, which does not create its own `this` binding, but passes in the lexical `this` (i.e. the `this` in an arrow function is the same `this` as the context it is called in):

```
$('#mm').on('hide.bs.modal', () => {
   this.checkLogged();
});
```